# Design system debt calculation

Tags: calculus, analysis, average, math-software, data-analysis

Thanks in advance for your help.
I am a designer working on a software platform.
I am working on a calculation that captures the amount of redundancy/design debt in our design system on a component level.

Say there are 50 different components in our system.
e.g Buttons, fonts, tabs, links etc.

For example, let's say there is currently:
4 different types of buttons when there should only be 1 unique type and
there are also 2 types of links when we only want 1.
There are 6 types of links when we only want 2.

[ (4 total buttons/ 1 unique button) + (2 total links/1 unique link) + (6 total links/2 unique links) /3] -100 = design debt score

We want to land on a % that captures the amount of redundancy overall and bring this down to 0% (whereby the the total number of buttons is the same number as the number of unique buttons).
Should I simply get an average of all of the components and minus 100?

Is this related to a duplication rate calculation?